# How can I modify an int type argument to a T type?

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

Hello I'm trying to learn chisel and I'm compiling an existing project, but I get a problem with the mem instantiation :

[image: Compile result]

How can i modify the int type to type T and what is type T ?

Waiting for your answers.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see the Chisel3 Wiki: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Memories

Answer (score 1):

type T needs to be a subtype of Data. It appears `numAddresses` is an Int

From the [UC Berkeley Chisel guide](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/manual.html) it looks like subtypes of Data include

- Bool, SInt or UInt
- Bundle or Vec

From [here](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Datatypes-in-Chisel) it looks like you could convert a Scala Int to a UInt as `numAddresses.U` (I assumed numAddresses is non-negative)

Comment: Thank you Joel for your answer. How can i define numAddresses as a subtype of Chisel.Data ?

Comment: this is what i get : value asUInt is not a member of Long
[error]     val numAddresses = scala.math.pow(2, addressSize).round.asUInt

Comment: isn't asUInt for casting SInt to UInt? don't you need `.U` rather than `.asUInt`?

Comment: value U is not a member of Long
[error]     val numAddresses = scala.math.pow(2, addressSize).round.U